# Word Count from File: Is it having problems opening the file, or have I coded it incorrectly?

Tags: python, file, count, cpu-word

### **Problem: Program seems to get stuck opening a file to read.**

My problem is that at the very beginning the program seems to be broken. It just displays

> [(1, 'C:\Users\....\Desktop\Sense_and_Sensibility.txt')]

over and over, never-ending.

(**NOTE:** .... is a replacement for the purpose of posting because my computer username is my full name).

I'm not sure if I've coded this completely incorrectly, or if it's having problems opening the file. Any help is appreciated.

The program should:

**1:** open a file, replace all punctuation with spaces, change all words to lowercase, then store them in a dictionary.

**2:** look at a list of words (stop words) that will be removed from the original dictionary.

**3:** count the remaining words and sort based on frequency.

```
fname = r"C:\Users\....\Desktop\Sense_and_Sensibility.txt"  # file to read
swfilename = r"C:\Users\....\Desktop\stopwords.txt"  # words to delete


with open(fname) as file:                 # have the program run the file
    for line in file:  # loop through
        fname.replace('-.,"!?', " ")  # replace punc. with space
        words = fname.lower()  # make all words lowercase

        word_list = fname.split()  # separate the words, store

        word_dict = {}  # create a dictionary


with open(swfilename) as delete:  # open stop word list
    for line in delete:
        sw_list = swfilename.split()  # separate the words, store them
        sw_dict = {}

        for key in sw_dict:
            word_dict.pop(key, None)  # delete common words


for word in word_list:  # loop through
    word_dict[word] = word_dict.get(word, 0) + 1  # count frequency

word_freq = []  # create index
for key, value in word_dict.items():  # count occurrences
    word_freq.append((value, key))  # append freq list

word_freq.sort(reverse=True)  # sort the words by freq
print(word_freq)  # print most to least
```

Comment: The only word you ever add to the word list is the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Importing files in windows using python is some what different when compared to Mac and Linux OS

Just change the path of file from `fname = r"C:\Users\....\Desktop\Sense_and_Sensibility.txt"`

To `fname = "C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\Sense_and_Sensibility.txt"`

Use double slashes

Comment: Are you sure? For starting those files are opened, not imported (which in Python would imply that they are used through `import`). Aside of that, the `r` (standing for *raw*) qualifiers actually ignores C-style escaping, meaning that \  is treated always as \\ , and there is no need for escaping it with \\ nor that it will have a special intepretation, e.g. as `\t` would.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code. I would only discuss the most obvious one, given that it is impossible to reproduce your exact observations because the input you are using is not accessible to the readers.

I will first report your code verbatim and mark weak points with `???` followed by a number, which I will address after the code.

```
fname = r"C:\Users\....\Desktop\Sense_and_Sensibility.txt" #file to read
swfilename = r"C:\Users\....\Desktop\stopwords.txt"        #words to delete



with open(fname) as file:                 #???(1) have the program run the file  
    for line in file:                     #loop through                                     
       fname.replace ('-.,"!?', " ")         #???(2) replace punc. with space
       words = fname.lower()                 #???(3) make all words lowercase

       word_list = fname.split()             #separate the words, store 

       word_dict = {}                        #???(4) create a dictionary 





    with open(swfilename) as delete:       #open stop word list
        for line in delete: 
            sw_list = swfilename.split()   #separate the words, store them 
            sw_dict = {}

            for key in sw_dict:
                word_dict.pop(key, None)    #???(5) delete common words




    for word in word_list:                            #???(6) loop through
        word_dict[word] = word_dict.get(word, 0) + 1  #???(7) count frequency

    word_freq = []                                    #???(8)create index
    for key, value in word_dict.items():              #count occurrences           
        word_freq.append((value, key))                #append freq list         

    word_freq.sort(reverse = True)                  #sort the words by freq
    print(word_freq)                                #print most to least
```

1. (minor) `file` is a reserved word in Python, and it is a good practice not to use for custom purposes as you are doing
2. (major) `.replace()` will replace the exact string on the left with the exact string on the right, but what you would like to do is to perform some sort of `multi_replace()`, which you could implement yourself (for example as a function) by consecutive calls to `.replace()` for example in a loop (or using `functools.reduce()`).
3. (major) `fname` contains the file name (path, actually) and not the content of the file you want to work with.
4. (major) You are looping through the lines of the file, but if you create your `word_list` and `word_dict` for each line, you will "overwrite" the content at each iteration. Also, the `word_dict` is created empty and never filled.
5. (major) The logic you are trying to implement will not work on a dictionary, because dictionaries cannot contain multiple identical keys. A more effective approach would be to create a `filtered_list` from the `word_list` by excluding the `stop_words`. The dictionary can then be used to implement a counter. I do understand that at your level it may be worth learning how to implement a counter, but please keep in mind that the module `collections.Counter()` from the standard library (thus accessible using `import collections`) does exactly what you want.
6. (major) given that at this point there is nothing useful left from your code, but looping through the original list instead of through the filtered list will have no information about the stop words.
7. (major) `dictionary[key]` can be used both for accessing (which you do not do) and for writing (which you do) the value associated to a specific key in a dictionary.
8. (minor) Obviously, your approach for sorting according to word frequency would work, but a much better approach would be to use the parameter `key` of `.sort()` and `sorted()`.

Hope this helps!